# Cannot convert String to int in Java

Tags: java

In my program I need to convert a String to Int.

```
    String str = new String(request.getData());

    String [] setting = str.split(" ");        
    String bs = setting[1];
```

The value of bs is 1024, I use `System.out.println` to test it, and it displays on the screen with "1024".

But when I use

```
    int blockSize = Integer.parseInt(bs);
```

it will return an exception point to the line of `Integer.parseInt` :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1024"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
```

Can someone help me to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure bs contains 1024, because if so, then you shouldn't be getting any problem.

Comment: @darknight, I don't think it's an issue of excessive whitespace since he's using a space as a delimiter.

Comment: i think your bs contains `string` value not a `integer` that's why this error. make sure `setting[postion]` is an `integer` value. i mean like "somevalue".

Comment: @jacobbb - I suspect you have invisible characters in there. `bs.length()` would probably be helpful, and possibly even a loop over the characters outputting their character code: `for (char ch : bs.toCharArray() ) { System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(ch)); }`

Comment: I think the issue is with some unicode hidden character. Test the length of the string and check if it is really 4.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks, i tried bs.length, and the return value is 1019... how can it be this value? I used "bs = bs.replaceAll("\\D", "");" as enrico suggested, solved the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you have some hidden unicode character in the string `bs`, you can remove the non-digits with:

```
bs = bs.replaceAll("\\D", "");
int blockSize = Integer.parseInt(bs);
```

The code above will also convert the string `"1a2"` to `12`, but that doesn't seem your case.

Comment: I tried bs.length(), the return value is 1019... and I used "bs = bs.replaceAll("\\D", "");" , problem solved, thanks.

Comment: yeah..1019..idk why, the array setting[] is i sending from datagramSocket, is there sth to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 String bs = setting[1].trim().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while( (!bs.matches("\\d+")) && (bs.length > 1)) 
    {
        bs = bs.substring(1);
    }

    if (bs.matches("\\d+")
    {
        int blockSize = Integer.parseInt(bs);
    }
    else
    {
        int blockSize = -1;
    }
    /* !! Then, check for "-1" in your application of 
          block size #runtime_exception_prevention */
```

This will continue to remove the offensive non digit bits down to 1, as necessary, until a digit is found or only one character remains in the string. The second check prevents the exception and returns a flagged value. Checking for this flagged value will intercept runtime exceptions.
NB: I wrote this code in the comment block, please forgive any minor errors, I will gladly correct.